# I'm ready in the meaning I've just finished something

Tags: word-usage

I saw the answer to the I'm finished == I'm ready entry but it seems to me that the answers miss the point. What my question is, and probably the user before me also wanted an answer to is, if I'm ready can be used in the meaning of I have just completed something.
It is clear that to be ready means you are prepared to start a next course of action, but is it good English or at least does it sound natural if I use it at the *end* of an activity implicating that I am over it now. (using the phrase I' ready in the meaning of I have just finished something.) Like when you have just made 40 burpees and you sigh: I'm ready.

Or for example you are doing your morning exercise and your brother wants to go somewhere with you and to his suggestion you answer: "Ok, we can go when I am ready."

Answer (score 2):

"I'm ready" implies there is something known that you are ready for.

So if you reached the absolute end of a task with no apparent next task, it would not sound right to say "I'm ready."

But if you were at a restaurant with coworkers and had just finished eating and paying the bill, you might say "I'm ready" as a sign that you are done with lunch and are ready to go back to work. Going back to work was the known next step so everyone realizes that's what you are ready to do.

But if you just finished an exercise routine and there was no apparent next step, you wouldn't just say "I'm ready." Ready for what? To take a shower? To go home? To do more pushups? With no known next step, it would sound more natural to say "I'm done."

Answer (score 0):

I'm ready = I'm prepared. So it depends on the context.

In your burping example, you do not state what you are 'ready'/preparing for, so it does not fit very well.

However in your morning exercise example, it is implied that you are 'ready'/'preparing' for going with your brother, so it does make sense.